# Rectangle Needed To Make Cone

Tags: circles, convex-cone

This is practical problem. I want to make a lampshade (actually many 
of them). It is made by rolling a piece of paper into a non-closed 
cone shape. The base is wider than the top.

Given: the length of a side, the top diameter, and the bottom 
diameter.

I need a formula that will take those three variables and output the 
X and Y dimensions of the piece of paper which will just inscribe the 
pattern. I can't even figure out whether this is a geometry, trig, or 
calculus problem.

Comment: Sounds like you want to *circumscribe* a rectangle if you’re going to cut material out. You can find the angle of the cone from the height and difference in diameters. From that, you can work out the “unrolled” radii of the top and bottom edges.

Comment: See this reference https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Understanding-Cylinder-Targets-Math